# Bitmap image in polar coordinates

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0, bitmapimage, polar-coordinates

I got an interesting situation. I need to produce something like: 
[image]

It is a standard polar coordinate image, so it is a raster. I already know the color values of pixels in polar coordinate system. But I dont know how to make a bitmap image by assigning polar coordinates.

How do we render a polar coordinate system in wpf? Any heads up or tips are deeply appreciated.

Feel free to ask further details.

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen [writeablebitmapex](http://writeablebitmapex.codeplex.com/) ?